# Submitting a form by clicking a radio button, then running ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, radio-button, form-submit

I have a checkout form, that worked in everything but IE8.
I am altering it to save input results as session data using ajax.
When i was using the first 'click' function, all was well, but I cant get the 'submit' function to fire (no alert). The following show/hide is working.
I need another set of eyes on this please.

The form

```
<form name="payment_method_form" id="payment_method_form" method="post">
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="cc"> Credit Card
  </div>
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="pp"> Paypal
  </div>
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="dd"> Direct Deposit
  </div>
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="cash"> Cash on Delivery
  </div>
</form>
```

The Script (is enclosed in $(document).ready())

```
$('input[name$="pay_method"]').click(function() {
        $('#payment_method_form').submit(function(e) {
            alert("clicked")
            <!-- ajax here -->
        });
    var pay_method = $(this).val();
    $('.pay_option').hide();
    $("#"+pay_method).show();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` event listener has to be outside the `click` event listener, and you want to **trigger** the `submit` event in the `click` event as follows:

```
$('input[name$="pay_method"]').click(function() {
    //...
    $('#payment_method_form').submit(); //TRIGGER FORM SUBMIT EVENT
});
$('#payment_method_form').submit(function(e) { //START - Submit event listener
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked")
});
```

```js
$('input[name$="pay_method"]').click(function() {
  var pay_method = $(this).val();
  $('.pay_option').hide();
  $("#" + pay_method).show();
  $('#payment_method_form').submit();
});
$('#payment_method_form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("clicked")
    //<!-- ajax here -->
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="payment_method_form" id="payment_method_form" method="post">
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="cc">Credit Card
  </div>
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="pp">Paypal
  </div>
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="dd">Direct Deposit
  </div>
  <div class="pay_method">
    <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="cash">Cash on Delivery
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Worked a treat, Greatly appreciated.